# Cannot implicitly convert type string to int. (in product.price) which is int in db

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private Product CreateProduct()
{
    Product product = new Product();

    product.Name = txtName.Text;
    ***product.Price = txtPrice.Text;***  
    product.TypeId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlType.SelectedValue);
    product.Description = txtDescription.Text;
    product.Image = ddlImage.SelectedValue;

    return product;
}
```

The datatype of `price` is `int` in db and here it gives error on   `product.Price = txtPrice.Text;`:

> cannot implicitly convert type string to int.

Please tell me if I have to convert it or change the data type in db.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You _know_ how to convert it since you _already_ use it for `ddlType.SelectedValue`. Why don't you use it `txtPrice.Text` as well?

Comment: @Ali so you are aware why it is happening, the `txtPrice.Text` will be a `string` and your DB type is an `int` so will need to convert the `string` in the same way you have for your `ddlType.SelectedValue` which too is a `string` mapping to an `int`.

Comment: Well as you already used `Convert.ToInt32` method i assume that you know how to convert string to int this. That's why i voted to close this question as the problem 'cannot be reproduced'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx) to converting it. like this:

```
product.Price = Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text);
```

It Converts your string value to a 32-bit signed integer.

Answer (score 0):

Either convert it or change the type in the database.

It call comes down to what you need for your application. If you're expecting prices with multiple digits i.e. 0.49, 100,02, 59,45 etc I'd use text or floating numbers.

If you're sure you're just going to accept integers then just convert your input to ints.

Comment: I wouldn't use text for money.  Especially when working on multiple regions.  SQL has a Money data type - use that or Decimal.  Float is just an approximation.